# android project set up in eclipse showing some error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

i had set up an android project in eclipse enviornment.
After the set up am getting the following error in Error log :

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3884)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3799)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3885)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3506)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory.newReceiver(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:57)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.deviceSelected(LogCatPanel.java:229)
at com.android.ddmuilib.SelectionDependentPanel.deviceSelected(SelectionDependentPanel.java:52)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.SelectionDependentViewPart.selectionChanged(SelectionDependentViewPart.java:67)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.DdmsPlugin$6.run(DdmsPlugin.java:690)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
... 22 more
```

always this error is there..so that i can't able to load the simulator.

Is it because of some wrong configuration.?
Experts please help.

Comment: need more info like eclipse version ADT version..

Comment: eclipse platform Version: 3.5.2.R35x_v20100210-0800-9hEiFzmFst-TiEn9hNYgDWg1XN8ulH_JvCNGB,   ADT Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

Comment: in eclipse do help -> check for Updates

Comment: Please also put your code, after running which you get this error.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a problem with your code. Is there any, or is that a brand new android project?

Make sure that when you go to execute your code for the first time you chose android application. Also if it is a new android project I would suggest that you try re installing the JDK and eclipse.

Good Luck!

Comment: earlier cases it was working fine. I didn't know what was happened at this time. I didn't change any config.

Comment: I would try to create a new project, and trying the emulator, and then if all is working well migrate your code piece by piece, trying the emulator at every step.

Comment: if i am simply creating a new android project without doing any code, then at that case also the same problem is there in the error log and can't run the app.

Comment: Try reinstalling eclipse, and the JDK. If all else fails try it on a new computer.

Comment: When it was working and at once it doesn't and there are many errors in many packages, the problem is in some key factor, that you'll not find by error messages solely. And for eclipse reinstall it is way too early.

Answer (score 0):

When I have at once many errors in console, I would look into the Problems view. (Maybe, you'll need to make it visible by window/show view). Almost sure, you will see some problems there. In this case you will know what problem to solve.